# Message not posted in Twitter using twitterizer dll in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterizer

Created one asp.net application and add the reference as twitterizer dll. In this application passed the oauth_consumerkey and oauth_consumersecret.Using the application i post the message in twitter but message not posted in twitter. So, i am using breakpoint in my code line by line.In the twitter response, result is unknown and the response content  will show error "{"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}". Please help me?

Answer (score 4):

The code is working fine just replace this line

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> response = TwitterStatus.Update(accesstoken, "Testing!! It works (hopefully)2.", new StatusUpdateOptions() { UseSSL = true, APIBaseAddress = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/" });
```

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you are using an older version of the Twitterizer library.  This issue was corrected on January 15th of this year:

https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer/commit/f6f1e5bb606986771dcd9841385d16aaf401cd83

I would recommend pulling the latest version of the code from GitHub:

https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer

Comment: I used Twitterizer2.dll from https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer/tree/develop/ExampleApplications/Twitterizer-Web/Bin. But it shown an error "A reference to "Twitterizer2.dll" could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM componenet " . How to add the dll file. kindly help me..

Comment: How to add references to a Visual Studio project is outside the scope of this question, but you can start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: Great!  Please mark my answer when you have the chance. :)

Comment: I am also facing the above issues. I have also get the SSL installed but still error is coming. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the library?